# I have a geoloaction field on account but i am not getting how to fetch map on the basis of geolocation

Tags: apex, visualforce

my field name is location on account and how can i get a map displayed upon it.
I am creating vf page which contains geolocatiobn but how can i get map displayed

Comment: how are you populating location field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your standard layout and add your VF page as inline VF page for account. here is the code where input field is for zip code and the map will populated after getting input.
`<apex:page docType="html-5.0" >
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript"  >
    function GetLocation() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = document.getElementById("zipcode").value;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = latitude;
                    document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML = longitude; 
                    document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude); 
                    var myOptions = {zoom: 4,center: latlng,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng, map: map, title: "My Location"});
                    document.getElementById("mark").innerHTML = marker;
                    alert("Status is."+mark);
                  } else {
                      alert("Request failed.");
                      }
            });
        }
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="zipcode" rows="3" cols="25" />
        <input type="button" onclick="GetLocation()" value="Get Location" /><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr><th>Latitude</th><th>Longitude</th><th>Address</th></tr>
            <tr><td id="lat"></td><td id="lon"></td><td id="address" ></td></tr>
         </table>
        <div id="map" style="height: 512px;width: 1024px;margon-top:20%; " >
       <apex:image value="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=1%20infinite%20loop%20cupertino%20ca%2095014&amp;zoom=16&amp;size=512x512&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;sensor=false" width="100%" height="100%" />
       </div>
    </body>
</apex:page>`

Comment: @ron you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use  to display location based in Account address in google map.

```
<apex:map width="500px" height="175px" zoomLevel="15" mapType="roadmap" 
                            center="{!accountObj.ShippingStreet},{!accountObj.ShippingCity},{!accountObj.ShippingState}">
   <apex:mapMarker title="{!accountObj.Name}" 
                        position="{!accountObj.ShippingStreet},{!accountObj.ShippingCity},{!accountObj.ShippingState}"/>
  </apex:map>
```

To enable map in sandbox follow this link:

[Spring ’15 Maps Opt-Out](http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2014/11/spring-15-maps-opt-out.html)